# Constraint validation is lost after entity inheritance

Tags: inheritance, constraints, symfony

I'm using an entity and this entity inherit from another entity. Everything is working fine except for one thing. It seems that the server side validation on the base entity fields is "lost".

Inherited class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * TicketBase
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class TicketBase
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    /* other fields */
```

Then:

```
use AppBundle\Repository\TicketRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ticket
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cheval_ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TicketRepository")
 */
class Ticket extends TicketBase
{
   /* only specific fields here */
```

After that, I can use any of my TicketBase fields in my Ticket entity no problem there, but when I create a form on Ticket, I have no server side validation on Ticket::title so I get an integrity constraint violation if title is empty.

Am I missing something to get my validation working ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

Controller action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/tickets/{uniqid}/{contactId}", name="contact_tickets")
 */
public function ticketsAction(Request $request, $contactId = null, $uniqid = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $contact = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Contact")
            ->findOneBy(array(
        'id' => $contactId,
        'uniqid' => $uniqid
    ));

    if ($contact === null) {
        return $this->go('contact_index');
    }

    $form = $this
            ->createForm(ContactTicketsType::class, $contact, ['method' => 'POST'])
            ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->setTicketsPrice($contact);
        $this->setTicketsNbJours($contact);
        $this->save($contact);
        $this->setTicketsCodeId($contact);
        return $this->go('payement_index', [
                    'contactId' => $contact->getId(),
                    'uniqid' => $contact->getUniqid(),
                        ]
        );
    }
}
```

My contact entity has this relationship with Ticket :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
 */
private $tickets;
```

And my ContactTicketsType :

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type\Contact;

use AppBundle\Form\Type\Ticket\TicketType;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\Ticketadd\TicketaddType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Description of ContactType
 */
class ContactTicketsType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * 
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('tickets', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => TicketType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ))
                // ...
        ;

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Contact'
        ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add manually the validation on my collection since cascade_validation has been removed in symfony 3, like that :

```
$builder
                ->add('tickets', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => TicketType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

It may come from you declared your $title attributes as private instead of protected.

Let's take the following exemple:

```
class Foo
{
    private $property;

    public function getProperty()
    {
        if (null === $this->property)
        {
            return 'foo';
        }
        return $this->property;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->property = 'bar';
    }
}

$child = new Bar();

echo $child->getProperty();
```

This code will return 'foo' because $property is not inherited from class Foo so the construct method actually does nothing. But if we change

```
private $property;
```

into

```
protected $property;
```

then

```
echo $child->getProperty();
```

will display 'bar'

**EDIT:**

Your problem actually comes from the embedded Ticket FormType and not from the inheritance. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138505/symfony2-validation-not-working-for-embedded-form-type) you have to enable the cascade_validation parameter on your Contact FormType

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Contact',
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
}
```

Otherwise only your Contact entity will be validated.

Comment: That makes sense, obviously, but I changed my properties to protected and have the exact same result... By the way, even if my title property was private, I could access and modify it through my extended entity... I don't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you try to set the validator on the getTitle method instead ?
Like described in [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/validation.html#getters)

Comment: hmm can you provide your controller ?

Comment: I've added some elements in the first message

Comment: Well, actually it did not change anything, but your answer lead me to the answer, thank you :) - actually cascade_validation has been removed in symfony 3